# how to get data props from another component in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, routes, router

I have component nabber/header that has a props, and I want to put the props in that component and then want to use that props on another props, how to put that props to get that data and transfer it to another component ? because I want to use that props to CRUD in database ? is that possible that we use $root to get that props which we put on App.vue ??

my components

header = [ props : 'list' ]
shop = add to cart, ( this which I want to transfer it to props list ) and go CRUD , is that possible ??

Comment: could you show some code to explain your problem?

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you supplied some code... One thing that is important to know: *is the second component which you wish to use the `nabber` data props on, is it a **child** of the `nabber`, or is it a **sibling** of the `nabber`?*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest learning a bit more about [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to solve this problem.

This will give you a logical place to define database related actions that can also provide reactive data to components that will display it. Even if you're relatively new to Vue, learning Vuex sooner rather than later will payoff.

It may also be possible for you to use `v-model` to extricate some data from one component... but what you've described seems a bit different. It might be worth looking at [how to implement v-model on your own components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) as you become more familiar with Vue!